# how to create a custom token in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am trying to create a custom token where, if a user inputs certain text in a rich text editor field, that text will display a value. So say the user inputs @@tester like, "Todays month is @@tester" in a rich text editor field. I have c# trying to find @@tester in any rich text editor field within sitecore, and if it finds that token to find that token in a title field that matches where the text is to be replaced. So ie:

```
Item Name = token
Item ID = {06912058-6U9A-4BBF-BAE3-9306974EBE68}
Title = @@tester
Content (rich text editor) = February
```

I have so far:

```
namespace LonzaWeb.Pipeline.RenderField
{
public class AddToken
{
    public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
        Item currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

        if ((args.FieldTypeKey == "rich text") && currentItem.TemplateID.ToString() == "{06912058-6U9A-4BBF-BAE3-9306974EBE68}")
        {

            var tItem = currentItem.Fields["Title"].ToString();

            if (tItem != null) {
                Regex regex = new Regex(tItem);
                Match match = regex.Match(tItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Also I am trying to use RegEx pattern matching. I have added this into the webconfig file to make sure it looks for it.

Comment: You need it to replace the value when rendering on the front page or on the Sitecore Back office?

Comment: on any page that has the Rich Text Editor

Comment: So you mean on your live site, right?

Comment: yes on the live site

Comment: So, why not replacing the @@tester before rendering it on the page? Once you have retrieve the text from the Rich Text Editor, you can search and replace the @@tester based on the value from your item token.

Comment: i dont follow, I'm not updating the content. So if a user wants to use @@tester on a page, save the value in sitecore and then days or weeks down the road they want to change the value, all they have to do is change the value in the field instead of every page that @@tester is on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109471/discussion-between-hishaam-namooya-and-keith).

Answer (score 6):

Extending the `<renderField>` pipeline is probably a better way to go.

A new type can be provided with its own Process method. The type of the field being processed can be checked with the RenderFieldArgs.FieldTypeKey. The FieldValue property can be updated with values for each supported token.

Each processor in the  pipeline will pass the resulting args to the next processor in line. I would add this patch after GetTextFieldValue.

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecorebetter/posts/2013/06/extending-the-sitecore-renderfield-pipeline.aspx

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/08/replace-tokens-in-rich-text-fields-using-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to render the rich text value on the Live site, you can do the replacement on Page Load. The below method can be a centralized one, so any other sublayouts that requires Rich Text Replacement can use it

```
public static string RichTextReplacer(Item currentItem, string fieldName)
{
   var richTextValue = currentItem.Fields[fieldName].Value;

   var getToken = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items.GetItem("path to your token item");

   var sb = new StringBuilder(richTextValue);

   sb.Replace(getToken.Fields["Title"].value, getToken.Fields.["Content"].value);

   return sb.ToString();
}
```

You can use the method as centralize and you just need to pass the different parameters that are required. You may add / remove parameters that suit your needs