# replacing a variable text with other text in c#

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am using c# and sitecore to basically use tokens in certain places ( see: [how to create a custom token in sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701532/how-to-create-a-custom-token-in-sitecore) ). I think I have a solution, but am not sure as to why it is not working, even though I am getting no errors.

```
Item tokenItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items["/sitecore/content/Site Content/Tokens"];

if (tokenItem.HasChildren)
{
    var sValue = args.FieldValue.ToString();

    foreach (Item child in tokenItem.Children)
    {
        if (child.Template.Name == "Token")
        {
            string home = child.Fields["Title"].Value;
            string hContent = child.Fields["Content"].Value;
            if (sValue.Contains(home))
            {
                home.Replace(home, hContent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

home and hContent pull up the correct values of each container, but when the page loads, it still has the "home" value inputted (the ie: @@sales) in the content area instead of the new value, which is stored in hContent. The sValue contains everything (tables, divs, text) and I was trying to single out a value that equals to "home" and replace the "home" value with hContent. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code is implemented as a processor for the RenderField pipeline, you need to put the result of your work back into args.  Try something like this:

```
Item tokenItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items["/sitecore/content/Site Content/Tokens"];

if (tokenItem.HasChildren)
{
    var sValue = args.Result.FirstPart;

    foreach (Item child in tokenItem.Children){
        if (child.Template.Name == "Token") {
            string home = child.Fields["Title"].Value;
            string hContent = child.Fields["Content"].Value;
            if (sValue.Contains(home)) {
                sValue = sValue.Replace(home, hContent);
            }
        }
    }

    args.Result.FirstPart = sValue;
}
```

Note that you need to be sure to patch this processor into the pipeline after the GetFieldValue processor.  That processor is responsible for pulling the field value into `args.Result.FirstPart`.

Answer (score 4):

You code isn't really doing anything. You seem to be replacing the tokens on the token item field itself (`child.Fields["Title"]` and `child.Fields["Content"]`), not on the output content stream.

Try the following, you need to set the args to the replaced value, replacing both the `FirstPart` and `LastPart` properties: [Replace Tokens in Rich Text Fields Using the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/08/replace-tokens-in-rich-text-fields-using-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx) (link to the code in the "untested prototype" link).

I would refactor your code to make it easier:

```
public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
{
    args.Result.FirstPart = this.Replace(args.Result.FirstPart);
    args.Result.LastPart = this.Replace(args.Result.LastPart);
}

protected string Replace(string input)
{
    Item tokenItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items["/sitecore/content/Site Content/Tokens"];

    if (tokenItem.HasChildren)
    {
        foreach (Item child in tokenItem.Children)
        {
            if (child.Template.Name == "Token")
            {
                string home = child.Fields["Title"].Value;
                string hContent = child.Fields["Content"].Value;
                if (input.Contains(home))
                {
                    return input.Replace(home, hContent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

This is still not optimal, but gets you closer.

Comment: i get an error with that line, Property or indexer 'Sitecore.Pipelines...FieldValue' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: curious though, what does adding in the args.Result.LastPart do?

Comment: It's used by different fields. For the RTE field you probably don't need to worry about it but for more complex field types (Links, images etc) then it is used.

Comment: +1 - @jammykam's answer is now more complete than mine.  As far as I know, the built-in processors don't use args.Result.LastPart for much other than closing tags.  But that's not guaranteed, so you should do it on both to CYA.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Do you know what happens when you performs `home.Replace(home, hContent);`, it will create a new instance by replacing the content of the come with what is in `hContent` so what you need to do is, assign this instance to a new variable or to `home` itself. hence the snippet will be like the following:

```
 if (sValue.Contains(home))
 {
    home = home.Replace(home, hContent);
 }
```

Comment: as in below, this does change the content, but it does not change in for the page. It still only recognizes the original content

Comment: So you need to change `child.Fields["Title"].Value` right?

Comment: I'm not changing any text within a field in sitecore, I am only using the 2 fields "Title" and "Content" to replace a certain word that equals the value in the "Title" field. ie: if @@sales is anywhere in the content area on a page, then it searches in a sitecore folder to find if a "Title" equals that text, if so, it goes down to the "Content" field of that same item and replaces what is in the "Content" field to the page where @@sales is, so @@sales will be no more and the content, lets say "February" will take its place

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
 home = home.Replace(home,hContent);
```

Comment: yeah this only replaces the content in c#, it doesn't translate onto the page